# Find $\frac{a}{b}$ when $2\log{(a -2b)} = \log{a} + \log{b}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I've tried rewriting the problem with some log identities, which led me to $$\log \left( (a-2b)^2 \right)= \log(ab).$$ I then set $(a-2b)^2 = ab$. Solving got me $(a,b) = (0,0)$, which was incorrect.

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You should also check the domain when solving problems

Comment: It's $(a-2b)^2$, not $(2a-b)^2$

Comment: What steps did you do after $(a-2b)^2 = ab$? There are many more solutions other than $(0,0)$.

Comment: " Solving got me " One equation; two unknowns will get you an *infinite* number of solutions.  Solve for $a$ *in terms of $b$* so $a = f(b)$ and then $\frac a{b} = \frac {f(b)}{a}$ may (or may not... but may) give you a constant.

Comment: Just to be kooky.   If $b=1$ and $a=4$ then $2\log(a-2b)= 2\log 2$ and $\log a + \log b= \log 4 + \log 1=\log 4 = \log 2^2 = 2\log 2$.  So $(a,b) = (4,1)$ is a solutions and also $(a-2b)^2 = 2^2 = 4$ and $ab = 4\cdot 1 = 4$.  So $(a,b) = (0,0)$ are not the only answer.  (And with know $(a,b) = (0,0)$ cant be an answer as $2\log(0 - 0) = 2\log 0$ is undefined as is $\log 0 + \log 0$.)

Answer (score 2):

Yiou get $a^2+4b^2-5ab=0$. Since $b\ne0$ divide by $b^2$. You will get a quadratic equation with respect to $a/b$.

Solution: $a/b=4$ or $1$. The second solution is impossible since $a,b>0, a-2b>0$.
.

The first solution is possible

Answer: $a/b=4$

Comment: Your first equation is wrong. It should be $a^2+4b^2-5ab=0$.

Comment: I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log((a-2b)^2)=\log(ab)$$
$$a^2-4ab+4b^2=ab$$
$$a^2-5ab+4b^2=0$$
Divide by $b^2$
$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}-5\frac{a}{b}+4=0$$
$$\frac ab=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{5^2-4\cdot4}}{2}=\frac{5\pm3}2$$
Note that the $a/b=1$ is not a good solution, since $a-2b$ would be less than $0$. So $$\frac ab=4$$

Answer (score 0):

$(a,b) = (0,0)$ are not that only solutions  to $(a-2b)^2 = ab$.

There are an infinite number of solutions.

But we know $a,b > 0$ (else $\log a, \log b$ would not be defined and we know that $a > 2b$ (else $\log (a-2b)$ would not be defined.

$(a-2b)^2 = ab$ so

$a^2 -4ab +4b^2 = ab$ so

$a^2 - 5ab + 4b^2 =0$

So $b = \frac {5a \pm \sqrt{25a^2 - 16a^2}}{8}=\frac {5a \pm 3a}8=a; \frac a4$

But $a > 2b$ so $b\ne a$ so $b = \frac a4$.

And $\frac ab = \frac a{\frac a4} = 4$.

But what is $a$? And what is $b$?  We don't know.  All we know is $a= 4b$.

========

Alternatively:

Let $\frac ab = k$.  Then $a = \frac ab\cdot b = bk$.

So $2(\log (a-2b)) = 2\log (bk -2b)=2\log(b\cdot(k-2))= 2[\log b + \log (k-2)]=2\log b + 2\log (k-2)$.

And $\log a + \log b = \log bk + \log b= \log b + \log k + \log b =2\log b + \log k$.

So $2\log b + 2\log(k-2) = 2\log b + \log k$

so $2\log(k-2) = \log k$

so $(k-2)^2 = k$

$k^2 -4k + 4 = k$ so

$k^2 - 5k + 4=(k-4)(k-1) = 0$ so $k = 1$ or $k = 4$.  But as $\log (k-2)$ exists, $k > 2$.  So $k = 4$.